# Public read, "private" retain property

Tags: objective-c

What is the best way to create a property that is readonly to public, and read/write to "private"? I could make a readonly method and declare the property in a nameless extension in the .m file, but preferably I'd like to keep the dot notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your public interface, declare the property read only i.e.

```
// Foo.h
@interface Foo
{
@private
    Baz* bar;
}
@property (readonly, retain) Baz* bar;

@end
```

In your implementation you can declare a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2), then you redeclare the property read/write:

```
// Foo.m

@interface Foo() // Note parentheses

@property (retain) Baz* bar;

@end

@implementation Foo

@synthesize bar;

@end
```

The above means that both the setter and getter will be created, but in files that include the header, only the getter will be known about.  The disadvantage is that the setter does actually exist so that if you ignore the compiler warnings and use the setter outside of Foo.m it will still work.

However, the advantage over just declaring a read only property and accessing the ivar directly is that you don't have to implement KVO manually and, of course, the memory management is done for you automatically.

Comment: I didn't realize you could declare it twice like that. Excellent!

Comment: @hyn: By the way, dot notation has nothing to do with `@property`.  If you have a method declared as `-(Baz*) bar;` you can use dot notation to access it.

Comment: Doing this in XCode 9 it crashes saying no setXXXX method exists when trying to use "self.XXXX = someObj;" Have they taken this "feature" away?

Answer (score 2):

Usually people create an instance var and pair it with readonly property in `@synthesize` statement. The ivar, though, won't be accessible via dot notation. You'd have to access it directly by its name.

Comment: I try to always access ivars through 'self.' because it keeps memory management somewhat simpler.